# oracle return all rows from a table if

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, join

Sorry, my description sucks, but the problem is easy to explain. I have a massive table (over 2bn rows) called BigTable which is partitioned by date that looks like this:

```
ID    Object   Date
---   -------  ----------
1     A         2018-10-01
1     B         2018-10-01 
1     C         2018-10-01
1     D         2018-10-01
2     M         2018-10-01
2     N         2018-10-01
2     O         2018-10-01 
3     X         2018-10-01
3     B         2018-10-01
```

I need a SQL that returns ALL rows for the ID where an Object = "B" and the date = '2018-10-01'
Therefore the result would be:

```
ID    Object   Date
---   -------  ----------
1     A         2018-10-01
1     B         2018-10-01 
1     C         2018-10-01
1     D         2018-10-01
3     X         2018-10-01
3     B         2018-10-01
```

The SQL is easy enough, just join the table to itself:

```
SELECT t2.id,t2.object, t2.date
FROM BigTable T1
join BigTable T2 on t2.id = t1.id
   AND t2.transaction_date = '01-OCT-2018'
   AND t2.object = 'B'
where t1.date = '01-OCT-2018'
```

This however runs for **HOURS**. Subquery does not make it any better. 
What is the most *efficient* way to return all rows for an ID that contains an object = 'B'?

Comment: Use `t2.transaction_date =  DATE '2018-10-01'` and `t1.date = DATE '2018-10-01'` to avoid implicit conversion. Create a local Index on  `(date, id, transaction_date, object)`

Comment: @KaushikNayak You should put that in an answer, because it's very likely that the implicit type conversion is his real problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, index already existed and suggested changes did not improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have good indexing in place...  No guarantees this will help, but have you tried a semi-join:

```
select
  t1.*
from BigTable T1
where
  t1.transaction_date = '01-OCT-2018' and
  exists (
    select null
    from BigTable T2
    where
      t2.transaction_date = t1.transaction_date and
      t2.transaction_date = '01-OCT-2018'
      t2.object = 'B'
)
```

The advantage of the semi-join is that once it finds a match it should "stop looking."

The join on transaction date may seem superfluous, but try it both ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can try window functions:

```
SELECT t.id, t.object, t.date
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             SUM(CASE WHEN t.object = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY t.id, t.transaction_date) as cnt
      FROM BigTable t
      WHERE t.transaction_date = DATE '2018-10-01'
     ) t
WHERE cnt > 0;
```

One possibility is that you misunderstand the partitioning, and the entire contents of the table are being read in your query.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using date strings directly while comparing it with dates. The reason being implicit conversion may not always use the available partitions on date. The documentation for [**Data type conversion**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-6DB331B5-0F34-4215-9A20-16AEA9D7FF4B) states that

> Algorithms for implicit conversion are subject to change across
>   software releases and among Oracle products. Behavior of explicit
>   conversions is more predictable.
>
> If implicit data type conversion occurs in an index expression, then
>   Oracle Database might not use the index because it is defined for the
>   pre-conversion data type. This can have a negative impact on
>   performance.

Thus, it is preferable to use the ANSI standard date literals

```
SELECT t2.id,t2.object, t2.date
FROM BigTable T1
join BigTable T2 on t2.id = t1.id
   AND t2.transaction_date = DATE '2018-10-01'
   AND t2.object = 'B'
where t1.date = DATE '2018-10-01'
```

Also, as already suggested in comments, create a `LOCAL INDEX` on `(date, id, transaction_date, object)` to further improve the speed of the scan using the index along with partition pruning.